# Некорректное отображение градиента в Safari 12.0.3

Tags: css, safari, кроссбраузерность

Имеется следующий код для задания фона элементу:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, $header-grad, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, $header-grad 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
```

В Chrome данный градиент отображается корректно: [image: http://joxi.ru/5mdYzP3h3JeLb2]
В Safari, наоборот, нет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить указанную ошибку?

Comment: картинки можно добавлять в тело сообщения просто нажав ctrl+v во время редактирования, когда она в буфере обмена, очень удобно, рекомендую

Comment: спасибо, поправил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполнил так, и градиент стал отображаться корректно:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(55,60,70, 0.8) 0%, rgba(55,60,70, 0) 100%);
```